# Update or refresh JavaFX 2.0 Stage

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I am trying to implement Internationalization in my application. I have text files from which I am reading translate to each language, then there is Options menu, from which user can select some Language, and choose that language as default. Here is the image of that: http://www4.slikomat.com/11/0316/gd7-inter.jpg

But I have one problem, when user select some language and click to button Save, it doesn't localize application. So user must close application, and start it again to localize it.

Is there any idea how to solve that problem? Maybe somehow to update, or refresh Stage?

Comment: What is your current save code?

Comment: Here it is: http://pastebin.com/GXiJ8erP Save is method under class Options.

Comment: What does MainPane.getInstance().doLayoutLanguage() do and how does it do it?

Comment: In general, I think the doLayoutLanguage routine would need to load the new properties for the internationalized text, then manually iterate over your labeled controls and call setText on them to update their text.  If you do that then JavaFX will detect the text has changed and automatically update the Stage to display the Scene in the chosen language.  So this is really an issue of how do you update the controls to display the internationalized text rather than how do you update or refresh the Stage.